# String Constant must End with double quote SQL report

Tags: sql, vb.net, t-sql, reporting

Below is the query for a sql report that I am completing in SQL Server Business Studio and I keep getting an error regarding the double quotes on this line  `Dim SelectClause as System.String =  ""`

I tried a few things but I get the repeating error.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Function getSelectClause(ByVal startDate as DateTime, ByVal endDate as  DateTime) as String
  Dim SelectClause as System.String =  "" 

SelectClause ="SELECT Define.meterName, SUM(Reading.volume) AS [Total Volume], MIN(Reading.time) AS [Month]

   FROM [Reading] INNER JOIN Define ON Reading.meterId = Define.meterId

   WHERE (Reading.[time] >= " & startDate & " AND Reading.[time]< " & endDate & ")
   AND Define.meterName IN ('007080')
   AND (Reading.dataQuality = '11' OR 
                  Reading.dataQuality = '10') AND (Reading.auditVersion = '0') 
   GROUP BY Define.meterName"

   return SelectClause
End Function
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

SSRS uses VB as its language for custom functions, which has a different syntax that SQL. VB does not support multi-line statements like SQL does.  You need to end each line with `" + _` and begin the continuation with `"`, and change how you append the date strings :

```
    Function getSelectClause(ByVal startDate as DateTime, ByVal endDate as  DateTime) as String
Dim SelectClause as System.String =  "" 

SelectClause ="SELECT Define.meterName, SUM(Reading.volume) AS [Total Volume], " + _
"  MIN(Reading.time) AS [Month]" + _
"   FROM [Reading] INNER JOIN Define ON Reading.meterId = Define.meterId" + _
"   WHERE (Reading.[time] >= '" + startDate + "' AND Reading.[time]<  '" + endDate+ "')" + _
"  AND Define.meterName IN ('007080')" + _
"  AND (Reading.dataQuality = '11' OR " + _
"                  Reading.dataQuality = '10') AND (Reading.auditVersion = '0') " + _
"  GROUP BY Define.meterName"

return SelectClause
```